# Skip tests in IntelliJ using Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, gradle

Does anyone know how I can skip JUnit tests in IntelliJ when doing a Gradle build like the following command line version? I have searched extensively for a solution but can't find one. I am in the process of converting an existing project to Gradle and need to support many developers that are not familiar with Gradle, some UX, some front end, and some Java. There are many broken Junit tests in the myriad modules and long-term we will fix them. Short term I need all other developers to use the tools they are familiar with to be able to do their job easily.

```
./gradlew build -x test
```

The Gradle-Android Compiler settings allow for command-line options but not non-android projects as shown in the IntelliJ settings dialog shown below.

[image]

Comment: In your IDE, do you have Gradle section under Preferences or under option where you can set defaults. You can specify it there. For ex: In Eclipse, if you go to Windows > Preferences > Gradle (left side pane) > Under "Program Arguments" select "use" (radio button) and give "-x test" then running Gradle build in eclipse won't run tests (unit tests).

Comment: No, there is no option to pass arguments. There is a VM arguments field but you cannot use that to skip tests.

Comment: I agreee as it's for Gradle's JVM (session) where you can pass JVM specific args. Now, how about under "Compiler" section, see if you add "-x test" in "Excludes" ? If you click on "Build Tools" (parent section of Gradle), do you see any tabs/options there?

Comment: Nope. None of those options are viable.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should be able to run a standard clean build from intellij if it's a gradle project (aka gradle integration in intellij). Then edit the configuration and add at the script parameters : -x test which will run the clean build (or any other task) without running tests.

[image: IntelliJ Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. Alternatively I guess I could have manually added the Gradle task to the run configurations with the parameter.

Comment: it is not `Script Parameters` but `Arguments` now with the last versions of Intellij. 2021.1.1 to be exact

Comment: this answer is outdated i believe .. Pls see @Abbin Vargheese answer

Answer (score 11):

From intellij 2021.2 onwards, type the argument directly in Run text

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I am using Intellij IDEA 2019.3 (Community Edition).
You can skip test using following settings.

[image]

You can get to this via Gradle panel located at right top corner.
Select `task -> Run Configuration -> Right click -> Edit Run Configuration..`

[image]